# How to switch a title on the same component?

Tags: angular

I have to change the header title 2 times on the same component.

So, my title is `My Title`, I enter several values then I press on `Search`

[image]

```
<div class="container-adapt">
<div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between" >
   <h1>My Title </h1>
</div>
<div class="separator-breadcrumb border-top"></div>
<div class="row" *ngIf="spinners.search">
<div class="col-12">
<div class="card mb-4" *ngIf="subPage === 'stocks'">
<div class="card-body">
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="name" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Name</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="searchSelected.name"
      style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
      placeholder="{{'1098' | t }}" autofocus>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="ticker" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Ticker</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <input id="ticker" name="ticker" type="text" class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="searchSelected.ticker"
      style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
      placeholder="{{'1321' | t }}" autofocus>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="isin" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">ISIN</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <input id="isin" name="isin" type="text" class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="searchSelected.isin"
      style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;width: 100%;"
      placeholder="{{'1337' | t }}" autofocus>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="filterForMarkets" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Market</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <select id="filterForMarkets" name="filterForMarkets" class="form-control"
         style="width:100%; max-width: 300px;" (change)="filterForMarkets($event.target.value)">
         <option value="">--{{'1074' | t }}--</option>
         <option *ngFor="let m of markets" value={{m.marketID}}>
            {{m.name}}
         </option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-4">
   <div class="col-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="launchSearch(modalConfirm)">
      Search
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedSecurityName.length > 0">
<div class="form-group row mt-4">
   <label for="selectedSecurityName" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Underlying</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-form-label">
      <span id="selectedSecurityName">
      <b>{{selectedSecurityName}}</b>
      </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="equityDate" class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-form-label">Expiration</label>
   <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
      <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
         <input id="equityDate" name="equityDate" type="text" class="form-control"
         style="background-color: white; max-width: 300px;"
         [(ngModel)]="search.equityDate" placeholder="{{'1916' | t}}" autofocus>
         <span style="color: red" *ngIf="searched && dateDoesntExist"></span>
         <span style="color: red" *ngIf="searched && dateNotValid"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When I press on Search, My Title must be must be replaced by `Title 2` for example. My problem is that `My Title` does not disappear, I do not understand why?

[image]

```
<div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between" *ngIf="!spinners.search">
   <h1>My title 2</h1>
   <button (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary">
   Back
   </button>
</div>
<div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="statusLine.open != 0">
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr style="background-color: #f8f9fa;">
   <td style="width: 13%;">Opening</td>
   <td style="width: 13%;">Highest</td>
   <td style="width: 13%;">Lowest</td>
   <td style="width: 13%;">Last</td>
   <td style="width: 15%;">Trend</td>
   <td style="width: 6%;">Time</td>
   <td style="width: 15%;">Day volume</td>
   <td style="width: 10%;"> Last update</td>
</tr>
```

I don't see how to switch from one title to another please?

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the title to a variable and change in the `Search` button's click handler.

**Controller (*.ts)**

```js
export SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'My Title';    // <-- default title

  launchSearch(modalConfirm: any) {
    title = 'Title 2';  // <-- change title here
    // do something else
  }
}
```

**Template (*.html)**

```html
<div class="breadcrumb d-flex justify-content-between" >
   <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
</div>
```

If you're starting with Angular, I'd suggest you to go through their [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) first. It introduces such basics.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either put the condition `*ngIf` to `container-adapt` instead of `row`

```
<div class="container-adapt" *ngIf="spinners.search">
```

Or you can bind the title to a variable and change the variable on search button and then remove the title section from the search results